# How to call REST API deployed in AWS on iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and trying to implement a webservice API GET call on iOS app. So following is the postman I have and trying to implement the same in iOS app;

[image]

But I am confused in setting this header on URLSession requests. I am not seeing much documentations regarding this. Looking forward for some help in implementing this on iOS app.

Tried to implement the Swift code generated in Postman :

[image]

But this implementation returns a Forbidden error message , so i believe some different implementation is needed to connect AWS

Comment: Look at the `Postman` console. The request should be documented there. This should give you enough information of how and what header you would need to set.

Comment: tried that , by setting the Authorization header , but getting "Forbidden" error response

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us what you have tried with [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) so far ?

As said by @burnsi, you show look at the raw headers that are working for you in Postman and try to replicate those.

Some headers should always be used for all requests (given a particular `URLSession`), so you should consider configuring your session using [httpAdditionalHeaders](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411532-httpadditionalheaders):

```swift
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Accept-Encoding": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    let session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
```

For headers that are request-specific or likely to change over time (like an authorization token), you should add them to the request itself using [setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1408793-setvalue):

```swift
   var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.setValue("XYZ", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Then you should perform the request using:

```swift
    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        print("Data: \(data?.debugDescription)\nResponse: \(response?.debugDescription)\nError: \(error?.debugDescription)")  
    })
```

Let us know what this code prints out for you and I'll try to help more!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support , I think for AWS the URLSession header implementation is different ,updated my question with the code I tried, could you please have a check

Comment: Thanks for completing your question.
Can you show us what the `Headers (8)` tab in Postman's upper section contains ? I suspect your `Authorization` header is still malformed.

Comment: Yes , this is the values for Authorization in header - **AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA3ONF/20221123/us-east-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=37ff5e60509dd2ba**